# Yii2 Sluggable Behavior update existing rows in DB

Tags: yii2, behavior

I have a table

```
--------------------
 id |title   | slug
--------------------
 1  | name_1 | 
--------------------
 1  | name_2 | 
--------------------
```

How can i update column slug from colunm "title" using yii2 sluggable behavior

Code bellow don't work

```
$this->update('event', ['slug' => (new Expression(Inflector::slug('title')))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the SluggableBehavior to the Model

```
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;

class YourModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'title',
                // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The slugAttribute isn't needed since our column is called slug, the framework default.

Comment: but how can i get list of refferenses to my elements, if slug is empty?

Comment: I think you need to do this manually or create function which fetch rows one by one and update its slug.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I used write console action like

```
public function actionEventSlugs(){
    $events = \frontend\models\Events::find()->all();
    foreach($events as $event){
        $slug = \yii\helpers\Inflector::slug($event->title);
        $event->slug = $slug;
       // $this->stdout($slug."/n");            
        $event->update(false);
    }
}
```

and start the console and simply execute the command

```
yii build/event-slug
```

This could better for your production also.
Here 'build' is the controller name

May it helps

Thanks